# VS-Code Prettier Format On Save doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

For about a month now, my Prettier extension has stopped working as it normally does. Most notably - format on save does not work. Other notes:

- Format on typing a `;` works
- I get this error type symbol in the status bar next to the Prettier button - I can't find any reference to this relating to Prettier on Google:

[image]]

- I have my format on save checked in Settings:

[image: Format on save]

- `Format Document`, `Format Selection` and `Format Document with` command palette options all do nothing
- Timing of the break coincides with moving from Prettier 2-3
- I've followed the migration steps and think all is in order. Some snippets of the configuration between eslint and prettier that I have:

1. As per [the prettier documentation](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#linter-integration), my VS Code settings has:

```json
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true, // (even though VSCode has this as deprecated), have tried with and without this line
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true,
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
```

2. My Dev dependencies include:

```json
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^9.0.0",
```

3. I have a `prettier.config.js` file
4. My `.eslintrc.js` file includes:

```js
extends: ['airbnb', 'prettier'],
plugins: ['react', 'jsx-a11y', 'import', 'react-hooks', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],
```

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this or further debugging tests to do here? It's driving me nuts!

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Check out the readme [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode).  Especially the part about "breaking changes  between 2.x and 3.x).  Uninstall and reinstall.  3) Ensure you install the latest/greatest version.  4) Post back what you find.

Comment: Have uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version. The migration from 2-3 timing seems about right in terms of when things broke for me, so it seems likely that this is related to that. I've updated my qn with the relevant migration steps taken. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: It sounds like others are experiencing the same problem: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/1156

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Format Document (in pop-up bar)
3. Select `Format Document`
4. Select `Configure Default Formatter...`
5. Select `Prettier - Code formatter`

Done!

Comment: I noticed that prettier was not working after a VS code update. I don't know if it has to do with the problem but if it is, then the problem may re-appear on future updates, and this solution may work again on those cases.

Comment: Cheers mate. This seemed to resolve itself (I tried a million things and not really sure which one of them worked). I do understand it a bit better and can see the logic behind your process. For me, the configuration was already set to Prettier but it still wasn't working (you can see that Prettier has been configured, I think by virtue of the Prettier button on the bottom right of the first screenshot.

Comment: Also! If there's any syntax error, or a comment is unclosed somewhere in script, format on save or Prettier won't work. Best of luck and happy hacking :)

Comment: Still helpful for VSCode Version: 1.55.0!

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately - already had Prettier set as default formatter and also format on save turned on.

Comment: didn't work for me!!!! set Prettier as default, format on save, restart VS Code. And still got a message saying Prettier cannot format my .js

Comment: Configure default formatter didn't show up on mine so I had to change the json and put in... "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode". In case anyone runs into this

Comment: When I select Format Document, it says "There is no formatter for 'apex' files installed.

Comment: Solved it for me! VS Code had 2 formatters for HTML.

Comment: doesn`r work for me

Comment: This worked for me with latest version of vs code OCt 23

Comment: FIRST please disable all extension then do it :) perfect work

Comment: This is such an old issue and I have no idea what the problem was. It fixed itself almost! Going to mark this as the correct answer as it seems to be the most upvoted according to others...

Comment: strong how this works when going to settings and setting/configuring the default formatter does not

Answer (score 84):

In VSCode settings, search for "Editor: Default Formatter", set it to esbenp.prettier-vscode and restart VSCode.

Comment: In newer version of VS code, it's now titled as "Prettier - Code formatter"

Answer (score 37):

On VScode go to **Settings > Text Editor > Formatting**

Then check the `Format On Save` checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Configuration has changed you need to add this into you vs-code settings:

According to the documentation: "You can enable Auto-Fix on Save for ESLint, TSLint or Stylelint and still have formatting and quick fixes"

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  // For ESLint
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
  // For TSLint
  "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
  // For Stylelint
  "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
}
```

Comment: Or `"source.fixAll": true` [to fix all generic linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41). I use 1.56.2 version of VSCode.

Answer (score 20):

For me, using prettier+(`svipas.prettier-plus`) -- because the default prettier plugin is no good -- ONLY changing:

`"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",`

to

`"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",`

solved my problem.

Comment: Thats what solved mine too! thanks

Comment: Seems to have solved my problems - wonder why the previous `"modificationsIfAvailable"` setting stopped working :/

Answer (score 18):

in my case the issue was that the default formatter setting was not being used for typescript files. Looking at my `settings.json` I saw

```
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
```

After adjusting the value for `[typescript]` the issue was resolved.
I couldn't find a place Settings UI where the default formatter can be changed for TS only, but it would be a nice feature though.

Comment: Thos worked for me too.

Comment: Working solution !!

Comment: This is the only thing worked in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Try to make your code prettier manually by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + P >>> Format Document. If your file is being formatted without any issues, it means that the issue lies in formatOnSave settings. Probably, you can try to make further debugging from there.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. When I followed these instructions, VS Code asked me which formatter I wanted to use to format the document even though prettier was already set in the settings.json file. I would add that if this does not work, then try running the prettier command from the command line to see if the binary is even installed, etc.

Comment: This worked for me. Same approach as Hamed's answer above, but a little better in my opinion since CTL + SHIFT + P gives you the option of selecting the value that Hamed suggests you type in manually (esbenp.prettier-vscode). Not sure what that value signifies, but I'm more comfortable selecting it from an editor option than typing it manually.

Answer (score 4):

For `formatonSave` was already `checked` and the `defaultFormatter` was prettier ... when I switched into `settings.json`, it was like!!

`"[javascript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": false }, "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true, "prettier.disableLanguages": [ "js"   ],`

**After changing it to**

`"[javascript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": true }, "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true, "prettier.disableLanguages": [],`

it did work...

Answer (score 1):

First check if Prettier works fine. You can try to format a single file using  `Shift + Cmd + P` and `Format Document`. If this doesn't work then it is most likely an issue with Prettier extension. Disable and Enable Prettier extension from Extensions.

If `Formant Document` works fine on single file then the best way to resolve these type of issues is going to `settings.json` and looking up the config. I had an issue where the first few lines in `settings.json` had issues and hence the other settings like format on save (`editor.formatOnSave`) and `defaultFormatter` which were below the ill-formatted line wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried checking the "format on save" box but it didn't do it for me, even prettier selected as a default formatter.
Editing the settings' json file worked for me :

1. Open the command palette with **ctrl + maj + p**
2. Search '**open settings json**'
3. Select the **user** option
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwL7K.png)
4. In the file look for "**editor.defaultFormatter**" for **html** (line 16 in my case)
5. Set its value to "**esbenp.prettier-vscode**"
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu0Ex.png)

Done

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a jsconfig.json file containing:

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

to my app directory, and reload Visual Code, in order for Prettier to work.
Also, I can't choose "Format Document With..." in the Visual Code command palette until I add this file.

Basically it tells Visual Code that the project is written in JavaScript (if I understand it correctly) and to exclude node_modules from intellisense.

This was after doing everything else people mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

I had one repo formatting on save and another not, in two different VSCode windows. The broken repo was using this filename:

```
// incorrect
.prettierrc.json
```

The functioning repo was using this filename:

```
// correct
.prettierrc
```

Dropping the `.json` extension corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont use prettier but What worked for me was , syncing my user with vs code.

[What should be "on"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFN6F.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution when using `black` to format Python scripts.

`Ctrl+Shift+P` and select `Open Settings (UI)`, type `Python Formatting` in the search bar, and then:

- `Python > Formatting: Black Path`: Specify the path where black executable file is located.
- `Python > Formatting: Provider`: Modify `none` to `black`.

  - This change makes my editor to work. Somehow this setting would be reset by some extensions or careless operations.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above doesn't work for you, check your settings.json file and confirm the defaultFormatter set for Javascript.

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll": true
    }
  },
```

In my own case, it was set `"vscode.typescript-language-features"` then I changed it to `esbenp.prettier-vscode` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For me the Prettier plugin for ESLint did not work in files using `import type` statements:
[Parsing error: '=' expected in `import type`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59833120/2326961)

The solution was to upgrade these packages:

```
yarn upgrade prettier@latest eslint-plugin-prettier@latest eslint-config-prettier@latest @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest @typescript-eslint/parser@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this fixed it:

after an update prettier was begin used as the following:

```
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint"
},
```

It started working after changing it to:

```
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```