# Parsing error: '=' expected in `import type`

Tags: create-react-app, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am using `create-react-app` with TS and do `import type` but eslint complains in VS Code saying that `Parsing error: '=' expected` when hovering `type` in `import type`.  I'm using eslint, 6.7.2

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The syntax is now supported by the latest versions of `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`.

---

ESLint support for TS `import type` syntax is working in progress.

Issue: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1436

Pull request: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/1465

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I have to wait for it to be released and be integrated with CRA.

Comment: Has this been resolved? It looks like it has been from typescript-eslint's side with this PR: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/1697

But updating to the latest version didn't solve this for me

Comment: @Christopher It works on my computer, can you try `npm i @typescript-eslint/parser@latest @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest`?

Comment: @golopot any other ideas why it might be failing after updating to latest?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue today even after updating to @typescript-eslint/parser@latest @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest

Comment: We have to wait for the next release of react-scripts after 3.4.3

Comment: @ZenVentzi In my case it was eslint reporting a prettier parsing error, so I had to upgrade Prettier as well.

Answer (score 7):

## Prettier

If you're using prettier rather than ESLint then the solutions is:

```
npm update prettier@latest
# Or yarn
yarn upgrade prettier@latest
```

Which installed prettier version "2.6.2". Which worked for me with `import type { } from './types'` syntax

Answer (score 0):

For me only this command fixed the issue:

```
yarn upgrade prettier@latest eslint-plugin-prettier@latest eslint-config-prettier@latest @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest @typescript-eslint/parser@latest
```