# Prettier Not Formatting on Save

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Pretty basic, but I'm stuck. Prettier extension is not formatting my code on save in VS Code.

- VS "Editor: Format on Save" in Settings is checked on.
- Prettier (latest version 9.3.0): Installed, enabled in settings, and is set to VS's default formatter.
- settings.json file looks like this...

`{"prettier.useTabs": true,`
`"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",`
`"editor.formatOnPaste": true,`
`"prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,`
`"prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,`
`"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",`
`"editor.formatOnSave": true }`

Still, Prettier isn't working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add Prettier as your 'Default Formatter'.
Check on @Hamed post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64510650)